# How to make input tag in fieldset tag required?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, fieldset

Using html and javascript I'm trying to make a sign up page, but I am not able to make input tag required in html code. Below code isn't working :
 `<input type="email" required name="email"  placeholder="Email"/>`
this are my html and css and java script code :

```js
//jQuery time
    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
    var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

    $(".next").click(function () {
        if (animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

        //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

        //show the next fieldset
        next_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function (now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                left = (now * 50) + "%";
                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({
                    'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
                    'position': 'absolute'
                });
                next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function () {
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

    $(".previous").click(function () {
        if (animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

        //de-activate current step on progressbar
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function (now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'left': left});
                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')', 'opacity': opacity});
            },
            duration: 800,
            complete: function () {
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            },
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

    $(".submit").click(function () {
        return false;
    })
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/

  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;

  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27ae60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27ae60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27ae60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/signup.css' %}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li>Social Profiles</li>
        <li>Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input type="email" required name="email"  placeholder="Email"/>
        <input type="password" required name="pass" required placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="password" required name="cpass" required placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network(Pleas Put Link)</h3>
        <input type="url" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter"/>
        <input type="url" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook"/>
        <input type="url" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus"/>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous"/>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" required name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
        <input type="text" required name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
        <input type="text" required name="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to make email and password and confirm password required inputs so that user can't go to next fieldset without filling this form.
Please help me and tell me what is my problem and why the required and the type="email" isn't working in `<input type="email" required name="email"  placeholder="Email"/>`?
**In addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I search and understand the only way to make filed required is getting values with javascript and check it and if it hasn't the proper format make user to change the input else submit the user input.
for more information:
[Check Html Values With JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` tag is a self-closing tag and should not have a `/` to close. See [here](https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/) for more details.

Try it like this:
`<input type="email" required name="email"  placeholder="Email">`